# Is there a way to force long lines to wrap in all e-readers

Tags: css, epub, ibooks

I have this epub that is made in indesign.
The main text flows just fine and wraps just as it is supposed to.

The problem is with the footnotes.
Long footnotes will not wrap but extend past the right side of the screen.
It does wrap in iBooks but not in Adobe Digital Editions or Bluefire reader.

Is there a way to force wrapping of long lines through css?

Here is a link to one of the xhtml files:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22417556/text.xhtml

and here is a link to the css:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22417556/styling.css
(indesign is doing a great job of putting a lot of extra junk in here so maybe that's the problem.)

Comment: What are the CSS definitions for the classes used for footnotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found <s>the</s> **a** solution! My "a" tags were styled with "white-space: pre;" When I commented out that line I got the footnotes wrapping as they were supposed to. Now I just wonder if removing that line may cause something else to misbehave.

Edit: changed it from pre to pre-wrap. It also works.